# AVAudioInputNode on macOS outputs only silence

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, audiounit, avaudioengine

I'm on macOS 10.14.5, Xcode 10.2.1, Swift 5, testing on a MacBook Pro 2018. I'm writing a simple Cocoa App (i.e. macOS only) that needs to listen to the microphone input and do something with it. However, the input node seems to output only silence.

I have tried the following approaches:

- **install a tap** on the inputNode to analyse input signal, then start the engine: the signal is always silence (only 0.0)
- **connect inputNode to mainMixerNode**, then start the engine: only silence is sent to output

In both cases, I have tried to specifically set the the format to `inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0)`, `inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)` and `nil`, but nothing changes.

I have tested with the following conditions:

- if the app is NOT sandboxed
- if the app is sandboxed, but with all permissions on (including microphone)
- if the MacBook has nothing plugged in (internal mic and loudspeakers used)
- if the MacBook has an apple headset plugged in

I created a new simplified project from scratch to illustrate the issue. Here is the only logic:

```swift
import Cocoa
import AVFoundation
import Accelerate

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    private let engine = AVAudioEngine()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func startWithTap(_ sender: Any) {
        engine.inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: engine.inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0)) {
            (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer!, time: AVAudioTime!) -> Void in
            var m : Float = 0.0
            vDSP_maxv((buffer.floatChannelData?[0])!, 1, &m, 1024)
            print(m) // Always prints 0.0
        }

        do {
            try engine.start()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func startLoop(_ sender: Any) {
        engine.connect(engine.inputNode, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: engine.inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0))

        do {
            try engine.start() // Only silence is sent to output
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect:

- in the case of the tap, that the app would print to console values different than 0.0, but only 0.0 is printed
- in the case of direct loop to output, that the app output sound, but only silence is sent to output.

Any clue? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the issue: the official Apple documentation states that it now necessary to actively request microphone access. I am pretty sure this was not the case before (the app would automatically request access when attempting to do so). All details are explained here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/requesting_authorization_for_media_capture_on_macos

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, but with both iOS Simulator and iPhone device. Even though the authorization was received, the input node outputs only silence. Can you please share code with your solution?

Comment: My code is a bit difficult to share, but in the end it is pretty much what you see above and the authorization request process describe in the link to the docs that i wrote in my answer